# Cannot match any routes: with Query Params

Tags: angular, router

I'm trying to call a route with an optional param.

My router

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: 'bo', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'bo', component: LayoutComponent, 
        children: [
            { path: '' , redirectTo: 'history', pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'history', component: HistoryComponent } ,
            { path: 'history/details:id', component: DetailsComponent }

        ]   
    },    
];
```

How i call it

```
this.router.navigate(['./details', {id: myVarID}], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Error: Cannot match any routes: 'bo/history/details;id=myIdValue'

But it works if i define it in the router with a slash and call it by manually inserting in the url:

```
{ path: 'history/details/:id', component: DetailsComponent }
```

Even if i add a ';' instead of a '/' in the router it does not work. I want to call the route with the router.navigate function!

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so it seems i made a big confusion.

I wanted to access the route with Query Parameters but without the slash, thus the solution is:

Route:

```
{ path: 'history/details', component: DetailsComponent }
```

Call:

```
this.router.navigate(['details', {id: myVarID}], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

/:id is not here, because the query params are not to be preceded by a slash and are optional. The route created will be /bo/history/details;id=myVarIDContents

And inside the details component i can get the query params as:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute)  { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.params.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: nowadays it would be  this.route.snapshot.queryParams['id'] as params returns an Observable

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: 'history/details:id', component: DetailsComponent }
```

change it to,

```
{ path: 'history/details/:id', component: DetailsComponent } //<----need to put router param after slash
```

and call it like,

```
this.router.navigate(['/details', {id: myVarID}]
```

Comment: Hey! it still does not work, the error is the same. I can call the route if i manually insert it with a slash but the function navigate calls it with a ';'